# Delete consecutive duplicates using linkedlist

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I have a 2D array with duplicated elements. I want to delete these consecutive duplicates using a linked list. So far, I am able to delete **just the first duplicate** for each value. Below is the code:

```
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def print(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Linked list is empty")
            return
        itr = self.head
        llstr = ''
        while itr:
            llstr += str(itr.data)+' --> ' if itr.next else str(itr.data)
            itr = itr.next
        print(llstr)

    def insert_at_end(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data, None)
            return
        itr = self.head
        while itr.next:
            itr = itr.next
        itr.next = Node(data, None)

    def get_cos_sim(self, a, b):
        cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
        return cos_sim

    def remove_duplicates(self, head):
      temp = head
      while temp.next != None:
          get_first_node = temp.data
          second_node = temp.next
          get_second_node = second_node.data
          cos_sim_value = self.get_cos_sim(get_first_node, get_second_node)
          if cos_sim_value >= 0.99:
              temp.next = temp.next.next
              temp = temp.next
        else:
              temp = temp.next
      return temp

    def insert_values(self, data_list):
        self.head = None
        for data in data_list:
            self.insert_at_end(data)


test_arr = [
    [0.11, 2.6875],
    [0.11, 2.6875],
    [100, 200],
    [100, 200],
    [100, 200],
    [0.11, 2.6875],
    [300, 400],
    [300, 400],
    [300, 400]
]

ll = LinkedList()
ll.insert_values(test_arr)
ll.remove_duplicates(ll.head)
ll.print()
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
[0.11, 2.6875] --> [100, 200] --> [100, 200] --> [0.11, 2.6875] --> [300, 400] --> [300, 400]
```

And this is the expected output:

```
[0.11, 2.6875] --> [100, 200]  --> [0.11, 2.6875] --> [300, 400]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you want to remove consecutive duplicates, then your expected output shouldn't be:  `[0.11, 2.6875] --> [100, 200]  --> [300, 400]` ??

Comment: I am comparing the node by node. when the consecutive nodes are same then that node should be removed. so the output should be 
[0.11, 2.6875] --> [100, 200]  --> [0.11, 2.6875] --> [300, 400]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is nothing really wrong with it, to keep this strategy intact you just have to apply the method `remove_duplicates` as many times as necessary, therefore, this might not be the most optimal solution if you are looking for performance, but it works:

```
def remove_duplicates(self, head):
    length = self.get_length()
    while True:
        temp = head
        while temp is not None and temp.next is not None:
            get_first_node = temp.data
            second_node = temp.next
            get_second_node = second_node.data
            cos_sim_value = self.get_cos_sim(get_first_node, get_second_node)
            if cos_sim_value >= 0.99:
                temp.next = temp.next.next
                temp = temp.next
            else:
                temp = temp.next
        count = self.get_length()
        if count == length:
            break
        else:
            length = count
    return temp
```

It is basically a recursive call, but as `head` is a public attribute of the class, this loop version makes more sense to me.

Also, do not forget to fix your indentations!

**Update**:

Just FYI, you could spare the function `remove_duplicates` by preprocessing the list `test_arr`:

```
from itertools import groupby

ll = LinkedList()
ll.insert_values([k for k, g in groupby(test_arr)])
ll.print()
```